# what is proper syntax for regex to get specific text from GTM attribute.response

Tags: javascript, regex, google-tag-manager

I used Google Tag Manager to create a custom data level variable to get the content of an ajax form. The result is in the attributes.response that looks like:

```
 response:"{\"current_url\":\"https:\\/\\/domainname.com\\/ +
          "manufacturer\\/category\\/model-number\\/\",\"h" +
          "tml"\":{\"cart_status_528\":\"\\n <div id=\\\"s" +
          ...
          "<a href=\\\"https:\\/\\/domainname.com\\/manufacturer"  +
          "-name\\/long-store-category-name\\/model-number-x\\/\\" +
          "\" class=\\\"ty-product-notification__product-name\\\"" +
          ">PRODUCT-NAME THAT I WANT<\\/a>\\n           " +
          ...
          "      <p><\\n more escaped html content          +  
          }"
```

I am trying to extract/parse the **attribute.response** to retrieve the PRODUCT-NAME text. I have tried the following which matches in regexr. But, GTM keeps complaining there is an error in my javascript at the double quote symbol. What am I missing? Or is there a cleaner way to retrieve the text? Thanks

```
function() {
var regex = (?<=product-name(.|\n)*">)(.*)(?=<\\\\\/a);
var attributesResponse = {{attributes.response}};
if(regex.test{{attributesResponse}}
var ProductAddedToCart = regex.exec(attributesResponse)[1];
return ProductAddedToCart;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please read the top answer here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Secondly, your JS has many problems. Even the SO code highlighter indicates it. See some [examples of how regex is used in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The proper way to solve your task, however, would be adding a dataLayer push with the proper response details neatly stored in a dataLayer object. You would normally ask your front-end developers to add a push in their response callback. It should be trivial for them to tackle. You can read more on DL [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer).